# Triple boot vista xp ubuntu

Tags: boot, grub2, windows, windows-xp, windows-vista

My partition table is pretty messed up from install/uninstall os and what I want to do now is to clear that and have vista/xp/ubuntu 12.04 on the same hard drive. I have create a new partition for xp on vista, everything was fine, but when I restarted my pc, I was getting the grub restore prompt. Even when I was trying to install xp, when the 'lunch windows' came, a wild BSOD appear. So I have deleted my partition for xp using gParted include in the 12.04 live cd. This haven't resolve the problem and I am still unable to boot in vista nor ubuntu. But I realy what this triple boot for LoL purpose (since my vista installation keep giving latency spike in this game and I hope this will not be the case in a fresh xp installation (I have tested it in ubuntu, the ping was good, but the fps wasn't).
So what I want to do, is to install xp on a partition, then be able to boot on any of them without a problem from a nice installation of grub or something.

[Edit]
So, I have XP on /dev/sda1, Vista on /dev/sda2 and Ubuntu on /dev/sda3, how do I configure grub2 for all those os? Here the result of fdisk.

```
Disk /dev/sda: 640.1 GB, 640135028736 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 77825 cylinders, total 1250263728 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0xd5d9d5d9

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1              63    41929649    20964793+   7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda2   *    41945088   558931885   258493399    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda3       558931968   646098943    43583488   83  Linux
/dev/sda4       646100992  1250260991   302080000    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
```

Thanks for help.
Sorry for my English.

Comment: I think I have erased my ubuntu according to gParted and my unsuccess to mount /dev/sda3

Comment: What OS you currently work? Vista and Ubuntu. Vista or Ubuntu. No one of both? And you have to install Vista before XP. Edit your post making it clearer and easier to understand.

Comment: I've just ran the boot-repair tool and this is my log  http://paste.ubuntu.com/1055345/
I'll see if this will work

Comment: Now I am able to boot on Ubuntu normally and on XP oddly using the Vista Loader in the grub menu, but I can't go on Vista. (the last entry in the grub menu was manually added by me and won't work, I have removed it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used the Windows Vista recovery cd and use the command prompt to type :

```
bootrec.exe /fixmbr
bootrec.exe /fixboot
```

This allowed me to boot Vista. Then I downloaded EasyBCD for setting up my bootloader for XP.

From then, I was able to boot XP or Vista.

Next step was to reinstall grub2 on the partition where Ubuntu was installed (I don't know if this was necessary, but I did it before testing if EasyBCD was able to add the bootloader for Ubuntu) by using Super Grub2 disk to boot on it. Then, I used EasyBCD to add Ubuntu.

Now, everything work fine, except for my ping in LoL... (it still doing those lags spikes in XP, so it must be my wireless antenna or something) Strangely, playing LoL using wine on ubuntu was giving me a stable ping on the same computer with the same hardware.

Anyways, thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

On your edit, you mention that you already have the three operating systems installed, and you ask on how to fix your bootloader in order to have a proper menu to select the OS you wish to load.

- You can use the [Boot-Repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair).

  > Boot-Repair is a simple tool to repair frequent boot issues you may encounter in Ubuntu like when you can't boot Ubuntu after installing Windows or another Linux distribution, or when you can't boot Windows after installing Ubuntu, or when GRUB is not displayed anymore, some upgrade breaks GRUB, etc.
- Or you can use [Super Grub2 Disk](http://www.supergrubdisk.org/super-grub2-disk/) to boot inside Ubuntu and then use the administrative tools to fix your bootloader.

  > The primary purpose of Super GRUB2 Disk is to help you boot into an OS whose bootloader is broken.

---

**Note:** Both solutions have a nice GUI easily usable to configure the bootloader with a few simple steps.

Comment: I've use Boot-Repair, and I can only boot to Ubuntu or XP, now I want to be able to boot on Vista, who is on /dev/sda2. How can I do that?

Comment: which windows have you installed first?

Comment: Vista, then ubuntu, and then XP, but ubuntu screw up (I have accidentally erase it in making a partition fot XP) and I have reinstall it. So the order is Vista, XP, Ubuntu.

Comment: Now seems just a question of fixing the boot.ini at your XP instalation for it to recognize the windows Vista. See [this link, on the "resolution" part](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/927817).

Answer (score 0):

You should install Vista, then XP, then Ubuntu (because Windows can be extra needy regarding partitions, and it can also overwrite your bootloader if you install Ubuntu before it).

Have you made sure that your XP disc is good and doesn't have a scratch on it?  During the actual installation process of XP, it shouldn't be relying on any of the information already on the hard drive, so that shouldn't cause a BSOD.  You might have some other hardware problem.

Comment: Ok, so I have installed XP and then Ubuntu (the first os installed was Vista). Now I can only boot on XP since I was trying to boot on Vista.

Comment: I solved my windows xp install using this link http://en.kioskea.net/forum/affich-118712-blue-screen-while-trying-to-install-xp

Answer (score 0):

Your Vista partition is 97% full. This may prevent it to boot. Remove >1Go of files (videos, music, images...) from it and reboot in order to check.

If Vista still doesn't boot, boot a Vista CD and type:

```
bootrec.exe /fixmbr
bootrec.exe /fixboot
```

Reboot. If you have direct access to Vista, it's perfect. Then use [Boot-Repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) to recover your GRUB menu.

Comment: I've already solved my problem following the steps on my previous answer.