# Can I install Ubuntu along with another Linux OS?

Tags: system-installation

I would like to install Ubuntu along with Mageia 3.

Comment: Of course you can there is no reason you cannot. just be sure not to overwrite your other Linux partition. I would recommend using manual partitioning

Answer (score 2):

Yes ,you can install ubuntu along with another linux distro.After installing ubuntu,boot into it ,open the terminal<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd> and run the below commands,

```
sudo update-grub
sudo shutdown -r now
```

These commands will detect if there was any os previously installed in this pc and then it update the `grub` to boot both the Os's.And then it restarts your pc.Now your grub will show both linux distro's.If you still facing problems on dual booting,then try [`boot-repair`](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair).

Comment: also may useful: http://askubuntu.com/a/154844/62483